# How can I clean the filter header of this datatable

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I have the following code where I load data in a datatable, and I add some filters by select, but when I create a new datatable this select multiply  in the head of the datatable

I have tried with the function destroy, but no resutl still multiply in the head

```js
$("#button_id").click(function(){


var dataSet = [
[ Math.random().toString(36).substring(7), Math.random().toString(36).substring(7), Math.random().toString(36).substring(3), Math.random(), "2011/04/25", "$320,800" ],
   [ Math.random().toString(36).substring(7), Math.random().toString(36).substring(7), Math.random().toString(36).substring(3), Math.random(), "2011/07/25", "$170,800" ]];

if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#dt_detalle'))
{
    var tables = $('.dataTable').DataTable();
    var table = tables.table('#dt_detalle');
    table.destroy();
    // alert('xx')
}

var op = $("#Txt_OP").val();
let tabla = $("#dt_detalle").DataTable({
    "destroy": true,
    initComplete: function() {
        this.api().columns(".searchable_option").every( function () {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<br><select class="browser-default" style="width:100%"><option value=""></option></select>')
            .appendTo($(column.header()))
            .on('change', function() {
                var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                    $(this).val()
                );
                column
                .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                .draw();
            });
            
            column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
                select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
            });
        });
    },
    "order": [
        [1, "asc"]
    ],
   data: dataSet,
    columns: [
        { title: "Name" },
        { title: "Position" },
        { title: "Office" },
        { title: "Extn." }
    ],
    "select": {
        "style": 'os',
        "items": 'cell'
    }
});
function actualizar() {
    /* Calculamos la suma mediante una función de reducción */
    let suma = tabla.cells( { selected: true } )
    .data()
    .reduce(function (a, b) {
        let x = parseFloat(a) || 0;
        let y = parseFloat(b) || 0;
        return x + y;
    }, 0
);
/* Asignamos al campo del formulario el resultado obtenido */
$('input[name="autosum"]').val(suma);
}

tabla
.on( 'select', actualizar )
.on( 'deselect', actualizar );

});
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script> 
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-3">
 <button type="button" id="button_id" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"><i class="fa fa-list"></i> &nbsp; look details 
 </button>
</div>
<!-- Modal: modalCart -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-fluid" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!--Header-->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">tittle</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <!--Body-->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="md-form input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text md-addon" id="inputGroupMaterial-sizing-sm">Suma</span>
                    </div>

                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="autosum" readonly>
                </div>

                <table id="dt_detalle" class="table table-hover table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="searchable_option">area</th>
                            <th>x</th>
                            <th class="searchable_option">number</th>
                            <th>x</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <!--Footer-->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope I have explained me well. Greetings

Comment: Please check your code example. It doesn't have any data. If you provide some sample data as well and make it work, it is easier to understand your question better and solve.

Comment: @pegasuspect I just fix this problem with the attribute `tittle`. thanks

Comment: You can answer your own question and accept it as well! Good job :)